# Debug common typescript project in Visual Code

Tags: html, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am new to typescript and I am trying to do something that seems like it should be easy but no one on my team has got it to work and I can't find an answer online.

I have a common folder with shared components that I package with **gulp**, I then have an application folder that uses this package.
So the structure is something like

```
root
  AppName
    node_modules
      CommonUi (with javascript)
    src
    ..files..
  CommonUi
    node_modules
    src
    ..files..
```

What I would like to do is run AppName and be able to put breakpoints in the typescript in CommonUi, if I debug CommonUi (point at the AppName url) the breakponits are disabled.

I assume I need a configuration setting to point at the CommonUi\src folder but I don't know where to put it.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Thanks, Vincent

Comment: It may be easier to use `npm link` to link the CommonUI referenced in AppName to the CommonUI sources. If you're trying to debug with your sources while running the published module, they may be out of sync.

Comment: That sounds good but the link is failing.  In CommonUi I run `npm link`, I confirmed the package number matches the one in AppName.  In AppName I delete the CommonUi module and then run `npm link CommonUi`.  I can see in explorer that `node_modules/CommonUi` is a symbolic link pointing to the CommonUi source folder.  Unfortunately then nothing works, in VSCode I get red lines under everything from CommonUi saying `[ts] Module '"C:/Source/CommonUi/trunk/index"' has no exported member ClassName` and `npm start` fails the same as it would if there was no folder.